# Why does my StreamWriter not write to file?

Tags: c#, logging, streamwriter

I'm making a log for my program using a StreamWriter to write to a file.  I have some code that looks like it works, but its only doing part of what it should.

I made a simple class called Log (code below).

```
public class Log
{
string path;
StreamWriter fs;
public Log(string fullPathToLogFile)
{
    path = fullPathToLogFile;
    fs = new StreamWriter(path);
    writeLog("Starting log");
}
public void writeLog(string s)
{
    fs.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy  H:mm:ss         ") + s);
}
public void closeLog()
{
    writeLog("Closing log");
    fs.WriteLine(); //add a blank line at the end
    fs.Close();

}
}
```

I made a simple test program that works perfectly.  It executes these three lines:

```
Log l = new Log(@"C:\Users\SADunkerton\Desktop\l.txt");
l.writeLog("testing log");
l.closeLog();
```

But in my much larger program, where I actually want to use the Log class, all I get is an empty file --no text inside.  Its code looks like this:

```
Log log = new Log(folderPDFs + @"\Log.txt"); //folderPDFs is a parameter of this method--it is a string that is a complete path to a destination folder.
log.writeLog("Beginning conversions");
//do some stuff, including write to the log
log.writeLog("Finished converting.  Success = " + success);
```

Can anyone tell me why the program version of this code isn't working?

Comment: your last example doesn't `closeLog`..

Comment: Have you thought about using something reliable and widely used like Log4Net rather than reinventing the wheel.

Comment: try switching on AutoFlush like this. fs = new StreamWriter(path) { AutoFlush = true};

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would rewrite your Log class to avoid the close part.
Just open, write and close after finishing the write part

```
class MySimpleLog
{
    private string _filename;
    public MySimpleLog(string filename)
    {
        _filename = filename;
    }

    public void AppendText(string msg)
    {
        // Create an instance of StreamWriter to write text to a file.
        // The using statement also closes the StreamWriter.
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(_filename, true))
        {
            // Add some text to the file.
            sw.WriteLine(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

In this way the using statement will close the stream and you don't have to worry about closing it. Indeed closing the stream could be very troublesome if something unexpected happens in your code. (Like an exception that change your code flow).

This is just a starting point to have the code tested and verified, but you could add some more complex logic following the pattern given. For example you could add a constructor with a flag to add a timestamp for everyline (or a flag to add a separator line, or a flag to recreate the file if exists...)

```
class MySimpleLog
{
    private string _filename;
    private bool _addtime;
    public MySimpleLog(string filename)
    {
        _filename = filename;
    }
    public MySimpleLog(string filename, bool addtime)
    {
        _filename = filename;
        _addtime = addtime;
    }

    public void AppendText(string msg)
    {
        // Create an instance of StreamWriter to write text to a file.
        // The using statement also closes the StreamWriter.
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(_filename, true))
        {
            // Add some text to the file.
            msg = (_addtime ? DateTime.Now.ToString() + ": " + msg : msg);
            sw.WriteLine(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

FINALLY: Keep in mind that specialized log libraries exists well tested and free to use. Perhaps you could invest some of your time in learning them

**[Log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/)**
**[NLog](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/)**

Comment: `File.AppendAllText()` no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @leppie You are right of course. The reason for StreamWriter is not apparent from this context, sometime I need to kill and recreate the log.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** You do not close the stream in the second example - and what will happen on garbage collection I am not sure. Call the `l.closeLog();` in the end to at least get some output. But it is not a good idea. What will happen if some method throws between `l.write();` and `l.closeLog;`. Something not good - file will left opened till GC deals with it.

**2.** You overwrite the file with each call. Probably what you need is to append the data - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3zc0w663(v=vs.110).aspx or even better change your code to use [File.AppendText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendtext(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
 public void writeLog(string s)
 {
    using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path)) 
    {
        sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy  H:mm:ss         ") + s);
    }   
}
```

And remove the `closeLog` method, because it is unnecessary.

**EDIT:**

The best idea is to just use stateless standard methods(as pointed by @leppie), that won't leak any resources:

It is [File.WriteAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375(v=vs.110).aspx) if you create one logfile for each log instance:

```
 public void writeLog(string s)
 {
     File.WriteAllText(path,
         DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy  H:mm:ss         ") + s);        
 }
```

or [File.AppendAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendalltext(v=vs.110).aspx) if you need to continue already existing logs:

```
 public void writeLog(string s)
 {
     File.AppendAllText(path,
         DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy  H:mm:ss         ") + s);        
 }
```

Comment: 1. You (and I) have made an assumption that the last example is a complete example, and two. The op isn't overwriting anything it would seem

Comment: Closing the log fixed it; thanks! I kinda can't believe I didn't see that myself.  I'm not too worried about overwriting the file --the path given was just for testing; I'm fairly certain I'm going to get a different destination path each time the method all this is in is called.

Comment: Instead of just leeching off other peoples answers you should try to credit them appropriately..

Comment: @Sayse What do you mean by leeching other peoples answers? I have just credited the post, and the post wasn't the answer - it was the comment.

Comment: @EugenePodskal - Your first edit was more or less a copy from Steve's answer, your second edit was Leppies comment (which you have since given credit to)

Comment: @Sayse My first edit - http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/25850561/1 contained two points with link to File.AppendText, just without the code sample. The example has been added during the grace period just a minute or so after the Steve's answer. And it is not a rocket science or form of art that cannot be created autonomously on my own. I have credited and elaborated on Leppie's comment, so I am not sure that there is a problem. It is not a one-line give-me rep plagiarised answer.